# nodejs - res.render does not work after jwt authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

When you press the Write button on the main page, you want to go to the writeBoard page.

Go to writeBoard.ejs only if you are logged in and validate jwt in auth_login.js.

However, res.render does not work after jwt authentication.

What's the problem?

main.js

```
app.get('/writeBoard', authMWRouter, (req, res) => {
    res.render('./basicBoard/writeBoard');
})
```

auth_login(authMWRouter)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { Account } = require('../models');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(3)
    const { authorization } = req.headers;
    const [tokenType, tokenValue] = authorization.split(' ');

    if (tokenType != 'Bearer') {
        res.status(400).send({
            result: "fail",
            modal_title: "로그인 필요",
            modal_body: "로그인을 해주세요."
        });
        return;
    }

    try {
        const { nickname } = jwt.verify(tokenValue, 'DongGyunKey');

        Account.findByPk(nickname).then((account) => {
            res.locals.account = account;
            next();
        });

        console.log(1)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({
            result: "fail",
            modal_title: "로그인 필요",
            modal_body: "로그인을 해주세요."
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

basicBoard.ejs (my main page)

```
            function move_writeBoard() {
                const write_ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("noticeModal"), {});

                write_ajax.onload = () => {
                    if (write_ajax.status == 400 || write_ajax.status == 401) {

                        responseTxt = JSON.parse(write_ajax.responseText);

                        const modalTitle = document.querySelector('#msgTitle');
                        var mtTxt = document.createTextNode(responseTxt['modal_title']);
                        modalTitle.appendChild(mtTxt);

                        const modalBody = document.querySelector('#msgbody');
                        var mbTxt = document.createTextNode(responseTxt['modal_body']);
                        modalBody.appendChild(mbTxt);

                        document.getElementById('exitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="/login"');
                        document.getElementById('correctButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location.href="/login"');
                        myModal.show();
                    }
                }

                write_ajax.onerror = () => {
                    console.error(write_ajax.responseText);
                }


                write_ajax.open('GET', '/writeBoard');
                write_ajax.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"));
                write_ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                write_ajax.send();
            }
```

Comment: JS programming question: why are you using the legacy `XMLHttpRequest` instead of the modern `fetch(...)` function?

Comment: ㄴ I didn't know because I studied JavaScript for a few days......